# Beginner proof that there can't exist a sample space for given conditions

Tags: probability

Given the following conditions ($A, B, C$ are events)$$
\operatorname{Pr}[A]=\operatorname{Pr}[B]=\operatorname{Pr}[C]=\frac{5}{6} \text { and } \operatorname{Pr}[A \cap B \cap C]=0
$$

I think that there isn't a sample space that can exhibit the above conditions, intuitively, but I don't know how to show it rigorously.

Comment: Because $Pr[A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c]\le Pr[A^c]+Pr[B^c]+Pr[C^c]$.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just say "I have *this* intuition", but either give your working or explain why your idea did not work. (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: use complementary sets, that is, observe that

$$
\Pr [A^\complement \cup B^\complement \cup C^\complement ]=1\,\land\, \Pr [A^\complement ]=\Pr [B^\complement ]=\Pr [C^\complement ]=\frac16
$$

cannot be true using the fact that any measure is sub-additive.